# Make the "eligible for bounty" time countdown

Tags: feature-request, bounties, live-refresh

I'm waiting for one of my questions to be eligible for bounty.

> question eligible for bounty in 14 minutes

However, "14 minutes" does not update without refreshing the page. Can we have this countdown client-side?

Comment: Very minor, but surely nice to have.

Comment: Would this be true for every question, or just those near the start of the eligible time?

Comment: Certainly not needed when still counting in hours I wouldn't think. Maybe make it trigger at the 1 hour mark to update on the minute